# Start up pre logon wallpaper location/infomaiton?

Tags: windows-10, boot, images, file-location

I really like the image that comes up right now, but how do I find out WHAT image it is and WHERE his picture was taken?? If I can find the image, I can find the location.

Answer (score 2):

I used this guide, it worked for me.

Source: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/find-windows-spotlight-lock-screen-images-windows-10/

First you have to enable "Show hidden files": Open a new File Explorer window and click on the View tab. Next, find and click Options on the far right of the File Explorer ribbon toolbar (you may need to adjust the size of your File Explorer window to see it). In the Folder Options window that appears, select the View tab and then, in the “Advanced Settings” list, click the button labeled Show hidden files, folders, and drives. Click Apply to save the change and then OK to close the Folder Options window

Now, in File Explorer navigate to This PC > C: > Users > [Your User Name] > AppData > Local > Packages > Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy > LocalState > Assets.

You’ll see your Assets folder filled with a few dozen crazy files, all lacking file extensions. These are the Window Spotlight lock screen images, in disguise so to speak, and formatted for various Windows 10 device screen sizes, such as phone, tablet, and desktop.

If you’re planning to use any of the Windows Spotlight images on your desktop PC or laptop, you’ll want the desktop-sized versions of these images, and these versions are generally the ones with the largest file sizes (switch File Explorer to the “Details” view and make sure the “Size” column is enabled to help you identify the correct images.

Edit: I just stumbled upon this utility, haven't tried it, but might be of use to you: http://vdsfreak.com/post/156133535205/lsr

> Lock Screen Reflection is a small FREE application that takes your
>   current lock screen image on Windows 10 (when set as Windows
>   Spotlight) and sets it as your desktop wallpaper. You can also save it
>   if you want to keep it to use another time.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no. Please include pertinent information directly in your answer, and cite any sites used as references.

Comment: fixed, hope that's better.

Comment: It's better.  If your not going to cite and quote the link, not sure the reason, you included it